# Authorizing in Blazor Server -side CRUD application for logged in users to view their specific data (not all data created by all users)

Tags: authorization, blazor, user-data

I feel very bad and a bit stupid to ask this question as it may look simple to many experts, but it made me work endlessly for a few days without getting my solution working correctly which is a bit frustrating.
Any help to get me out of this passe will be highly appreciated. The code link is at the end of this post.
All I need to work out is a way to use authorization in Blazor CRUD application so that logged in users can view only data specific to them (created by them after logging in).

What is the project? 
I have created an Assignment Reminder List(for students) that has a child component “AssignmentDetail” nested inside the parent named “AssignmentReminderList.
Child Component: Has the form to enable input data ( as a modal) and shows a list of assignments:

Important parts of the parent component code :

```
@if (assignmentList == null)
{
    <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
}
else
{
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Assignments</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Due Date</th>
                <th>Edit</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var assignment in assignmentList)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@assignment.Title</td>
                    <td>@assignment.Status</td>
                    <td>@assignment.DueDate</td>
                    <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="(()=>PrepareForEdit(assignment))" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#assignmentModal" value="Edit" /></td>
                    <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="(()=>PrepareForDelete(assignment))" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirmDeleteModal" value="Delete" /></td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}
<div>
    <input type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#assignmentModal" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add Task"
           @onclick="(()=>InitializeAssignmentObject())" />
</div>
<ConfirmDelete OnClick="@Delete"></ConfirmDelete>
<AssignmentDetail AssignmentObject="assignmentObject" OnSave="@Refreshed">
    <CustomHeader>@customHeader</CustomHeader>
</AssignmentDetail>


@code {
        List<AssignmentReminder> assignmentList;
        AssignmentReminder assignmentObject = new AssignmentReminder();
        string customHeader = string.Empty;
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;


        protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
        {
            assignmentList = await service.GetAssignments();
           await GetUserDetails();

        }

        string Message = "";
        public List<AssignmentReminder> AssignmentReminders { get; set; }



        private async Task GetUserDetails()
        {
            var authState = await AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
            var user = authState.User;

            //if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            //{
            var currentUser = await UserManager.GetUserAsync(user);

            var currentUserId = currentUser.Id;

            assignmentList = await _db.assignments.Where(a => a.OwnerID == currentUserId).ToListAsync();

        }

}
```

Model is:

```
public class AssignmentReminder
    {

        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        //User ID from AspNetUser table
        public string OwnerID { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Assignment title is required")]
        [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Title is too long.")]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Status is required")]
        public string Status { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Due Date is required")]
        public DateTime DueDate { get; set; }

    }
```

Now the issue is that the  GetUserDetails() method that I have created to filter and get the data specific to a user ends up in runtime Null Reference Exception, since I can’t get a way to fill the OwnerId (in the assignment Table which is the same as the userId from the AspNetUser table) when a record is created in the assignment table.

Project is available at : https://github.com/krchome/BlazorAssignmentReminder (for anyone who wishes to try it out at their end)

Comment: your link returns 404

Comment: your link is broken. Besides that, you have to manually set the ownerId of any entity of the type Assignement before you add them to the context. 
Also i don't get why you get a NullReferenceException, even if you did not set any ownerIds in the assignement table, the Where() method should return an IQueryable so you are not hitting the exception for this reason.
Are you injecting your application Context at the beginning of the Blazor page?

Comment: Sorry for the broken link. I have made it public now.

Comment: Are you still having this problem?

Comment: @MichaelWashington yes, please. Now the GitHub link is working if someone could help

Comment: It appears to me the issue was that you were not saving the current user when you created a new record. I also added a method to pull up only records for the current user. I submitted a pull request: https://github.com/krchome/BlazorAssignmentReminder/pull/1

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me the issue was that you were not saving the current user when you created a new record.

So I added this:

```
    private async Task HandleValidSubmit()
    {
        if (AssignmentObject.Id == 0)
        {
            var authState = await AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
            var user = authState.User;
            var currentUser = await UserManager.GetUserAsync(user);
            var currentUserId = currentUser.Id;
            AssignmentObject.OwnerID = currentUserId;
            await service.AddAssignment(AssignmentObject);
        }
        else
        {
            await service.EditAssignment(AssignmentObject);
        }
        await CloseTaskModal();
        //await HideInput();
        // await ShowInput();
        await OnSave.InvokeAsync(AssignmentObject);
        // DataChanged?.Invoke();
    }
```

I also added a method to pull up only records for the current user.

For your service I added this:

```
        public async Task<List<AssignmentReminder>> GetAssignmentsForUser(string OwnerID)
        {

            return await _context.assignments.Where(x => x.OwnerID == OwnerID).ToListAsync();
        }
```

Then changed the parent control to this:

```
@page "/taskreminder"

@using CRUDAppDemo.Data
@using CRUDAppDemo.Services
@using System.Data.Entity
@inject IAssignmentReminderService service
@inject IJSRuntime jsRuntime
@inject AuthenticationStateProvider AuthenticationStateProvider
@*@inject AssignmentReminderListAuthorization authorization*@
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
@inject IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor
@inject UserManager<IdentityUser> UserManager
@*@inject DI_BasePageModel di_page
    @inject AssignmentReminderListAuthorization authorize*@

<h1>Assignment Reminder</h1>


@if (assignmentList == null)
{
    <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
}
else
{
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Assignments</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Due Date</th>
                <th>Edit</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var assignment in assignmentList)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@assignment.Title</td>
                    <td>@assignment.Status</td>
                    <td>@assignment.DueDate</td>
                    <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="(()=>PrepareForEdit(assignment))" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#assignmentModal" value="Edit" /></td>
                    <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="(()=>PrepareForDelete(assignment))" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirmDeleteModal" value="Delete" /></td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}
<div>
    <input type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#assignmentModal" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add Task"
           @onclick="(()=>InitializeAssignmentObject())" />
</div>
<ConfirmDelete OnClick="@Delete"></ConfirmDelete>
<AssignmentDetail AssignmentObject="assignmentObject" OnSave="@GetUserDetails">
    <CustomHeader>@customHeader</CustomHeader>
</AssignmentDetail>


@code {
    List<AssignmentReminder> assignmentList;
    AssignmentReminder assignmentObject = new AssignmentReminder();
    string customHeader = string.Empty;
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;


    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await GetUserDetails();
    }

    private void InitializeAssignmentObject()
    {
        assignmentObject = new AssignmentReminder();
        assignmentObject.DueDate = DateTime.Now;
    }

    private void PrepareForEdit(AssignmentReminder assignmentReminder)
    {
        customHeader = "Edit Task";
        assignmentObject = assignmentReminder;
    }

    private void PrepareForDelete(AssignmentReminder assignmentReminder)
    {
        assignmentObject = assignmentReminder;
    }

    private async Task Delete()
    {
        var task = await service.DeleteAssignment(assignmentObject.Id);
        await jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>("HideModal", "confirmDeleteModal");
        assignmentList = await service.GetAssignments();
        assignmentObject = new AssignmentReminder();

    }
    //new code

    string Message = "";
    public List<AssignmentReminder> AssignmentReminders { get; set; }

    private async Task GetUserDetails()
    {
        var authState = await AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
        var user = authState.User;

        if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var currentUser = await UserManager.GetUserAsync(user);

            var currentUserId = currentUser.Id;

            assignmentList = await service.GetAssignmentsForUser(currentUserId);

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Hi @Michael, Thanks very much. I shall check and let you know.

Comment: This is now working perfectly with your changes. I just had to change a bit in the parent like this: `private async Task Delete()
    {
        var task = await service.DeleteAssignment(assignmentObject.Id);
        await jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>("HideModal", "confirmDeleteModal");
        await GetUserDetails();
        //assignmentList = await service.GetAssignments();
        //assignmentObject = new AssignmentReminder();

    }`

Comment: I'm glad it helped :)